# Selenium IDE selecting from the list which is powered by Google

Tags: selenium, testing, selenium-ide

I'm new to Selenium IDE and I need to run some test on one website. Everything seems to work just fine except the part where I need to select my location since that list is powered by Google I can't really get the object by list id.. 
Here's my test so far:

```
<tr>
    <td>open</td>
    <td>/</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=newregister-form-email</td>
    <td>javascript{&quot;test+&quot; + Math.floor(Math.random()*11111) + &quot;@gmail.com&quot;;}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=newregister-form-pass</td>
    <td>test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>clickAndWait</td>
    <td>css=input.submitLogin</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>waitForPageToLoad(1000)</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=u_users-form-name</td>
    <td>Tester</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=u_users-form-surname</td>
    <td>Test</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=u_users-form-phone</td>
    <td>javascript{&quot;+3706&quot; + Math.floor(Math.random()*11111);}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=cityinput</td>
    <td>Vilnius</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>pause</td>
    <td>1000</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=cityinput</td>
    <td>Vilnius</td>
</tr>
```

The last part is where I need to choose from the dropdown list but Selenium IDE doesn't see it when recording.

Thank you in advance

Update: 
This is html code of the city input :

```
<div class="row field">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-offset-3 formelement-wrapper">
        <input type="text" id="u_users-form-country" name="u_users-form[country]" value="" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row field">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-offset-3 formelement-wrapper">
        <input type="text" id="u_users-form-city" name="u_users-form[city]" value="" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row field">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-4 col-md-offset-3 formelement-wrapper">
        <input type="text" id='cityinput' placeholder="Miestas, Šalis">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you able to post the section of HTML you're testing against as well please

Answer (score 0):

instead of a pause you should use a waitForElementPresent on id=cityinput. This will allow you to wait until that element is present and not just 1 second (as your pause is currently doing)

```
<tr>
    <td>waitForElementPresent</td>
    <td>id=cityinput</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```